# creating custom control with powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell

I would like to know if there is a possibility to create a custom wpf control, adding some extra properties; **only using powershell** ?

Lets say, I would like to create a custom control derived from system.windows.controls.treviewitem, add/attach a couple of extra properties.

Anyone can show me some direction?

Thanks a lot.

EDITION 25.07.2017

Here is the interface I want to create :

[My Powershell Gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ybJn.png)

Comment: Do you have a sample of what you are trying to achieve? it might make it easier for others to respond.

Comment: I've added an image of the gui that I want to create. I have a WPF form with style template. When I add a treeviewItem, the look is customized. Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to have different icon for each treeviewItem. yesterday, I figured out the command-let, ADD-Member and I was able to add new member tot he treeviewitem. But somehow when I do the binding in wpf, it seems that it was not able to access to it. As the icons was empty. If I change the binding to a own property like TAG and add the image path there during runtime; I was able to reproduce the uploaded GUI.

Comment: So I have no idea why WPF can't access to the member that I created. And why it is able to access to the own property of treeviewitem like TAG.

any idea ?